# How to keep the state of HTML div after postback

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ckeditor, viewstate

I use [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/) in my webform application like this:

```
  <div class="editor" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
       <div cols="10" id="editor1" name="editor1" data-sample-short contenteditable="true" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
          TEST
       </div>
   </div>
```

---

I want to get `editor1.InnerText` after postback, and I can't because it's stateless HTML div, and at the same time I can't use server control equivalent because I already handled the required events on this control.
How to keep the data after postback?

Comment: Try using `HiddenField`?

Comment: @shrys: Could U recommend a specific scenario please

Comment: Use `<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>` for the CKEditor.

Comment: During any operation you can save it in a hidden field and while postback you can access and save editor1.InnerText in Session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a hidden Text Field as follows:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbTransfer" runat="server" TextMode="Multiline"></asp:TextBox>
```

In Javascript:

```
//Set Transfer Textbox display to none
document.getElementById('MainContent_tbTransfer').style.display = "none";

//Set Initial Source Code of CKEditor to Transfer TextBox's value
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(document.getElementById('MainContent_tbTransfer').value);

//Use this function for when you want to do the PostBack
function PostBack() {
    var temp = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();

    document.getElementById('MainContent_tbTransfer').value = temp.replace(/</g, "d123").replace(/>/g, "d321").replace(/&/g,"d111");
}
```

In Code Behind:

```
//Getting the HTML source code of CKEditor from the Transfer Textbox and Decrypting it
string htmlToSave = tbTransfer.Text.Replace("d123", "<").Replace("d321", ">").Replace("d111", "&");

//Setting back the Transfer Textbox's text to the decrypted HTML source code
//for when the page reloads at the end of the function,
//CKEditor sets its data = Transfer Textbox's Text
tbTransfer.Text = htmlToSave;
```

Encryption and Decryption of the HTML Code are necessary since Web Browsers will recognize the characters '<','>','&' as HTML tags and will not let you post back with plain HTML Text inside the Text box.

And do not forget to change 'MainContent_tbTransfer' if your text box has a different id in the browser